# Best/Simple hardware security token authentication for ASP.NET websites?

Tags: asp.net, security, authentication, token

I was recently asked to provide a quote on integrating a security solution like most Online Banks use, where there is a security token which key/numbers are randomly changing.

The portal is an ASP.NET website, 2.0...

I haven't implemented this type of security authentication before. Can anyone provide guidance, suggestions, experiences, etc, about the components/hardware they've worked with?

Thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The most secure way of doing it with a physical token is actually to use a third party product such as [RSA SecurId](http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=1156).  They also have a version for sending the token to a mobile device which is part of their "[On-demand Authenticators](http://www.rsa.com/node.aspx?id=3481)" offering.

Otherwise if you want to manufacture your own system then you need to consider:

- The lifetime of the token.

  - What length of time does the token need to be active for?
  - What happens if the client is in a different timezone than the server?
- The randomness of the token?

  - What method are you using to generate the token?  Last n digits of GUID? Psuedo Random number table? secret + userID + random number, hashed and then take last n digits?
  - What are the valid characters for a token?  [0-9]* | [a-zA-Z]* | [0-9A-F]* | etc.
  - What is the length of the token?
- Where is the token stored before it is validated?
- How secure is the mechanism used to transport the token?

  - Over HTTPS?
  - Over public SMS network?
- How does the user receive the token?

  - Rabo bank have a device which you unlock with a pin and then a code is issued.
  - Could have a device that you enter the given token and it issues the token you need to respond with?
- What happens if an expired token is presented?
- How many tries to you give them before you lock the device/access?

I was involved with putting a system together for a bank.  It was implemented using a mechanism similiar to that offered by the [Microsoft Federation Gateway](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/cc287610.aspx).  It might not have been for a Login but it was still used for Authentication.

Comment: Thanks David. The bank I use already uses that RSA token for two way authentication...and their portal is on .NET so basically I was looking for some pointers on how it all integrates on a .NET environment. Like do I need to have a server running somewhere specifically for providing/matching the keys somehow? Or is there a .NET component that I integrate directly into my existing AS.NET site? Any comments are greatly appreciated, thanks.

Comment: If you are using RSA then you will need to install their product in your environment and integrate to that using their components.  Which is either a webservice call or a call to a COM component.